# extract values from a list on python

Tags: python, database, for-loop

Im programming a webapp on python and on one part of the code i have to take a value from a database.
this value is on a list but this list is from a length of one. How can i take it out without making a for that will only run once?

btw this is the code

```
if not password and email:
    flash("Please enter an email and a password to login", category="error")
else:
    con = sqlite3.connect("DB.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", (email,))
    user = cur.fetchall()
    con.close()
    if not user:
        flash("This account doesn't exist")
    else:
        for User in user: #<-- this for
            pass
```

Comment: Why are you using `fetchall()` if you only want one row? Use `fetchone()`.

Comment: `else: user = user[0]`

Comment: BTW, `if not password and email:` should be `if not (password and email):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the list always has one element you can easily access the first element with `list[0]`

```
(our_user,) = user[0]
```

Edit: Thx @jedwards

Comment: When you need to do this, I'd suggest using syntax like `(our_user,) = user` (note: that comma is important) -- it does the same thing (setting `our_user` to the first element of `user`) but it also implicitly does length checking on the `user` iterable, raising an error if `len(user) != 1` (`ValueError` about too many values if the right-hand-side wasn't fully unpacked into the left)

Comment: Cool, didn't knew this. That is keeping future codes a lot cleaner :))

Answer (score 0):

If it has only a single element in it, then print the whole list:

```
print(*user)
```

or use the first and only element in the list

```
user[0]
```

Comment: He's not printing anything. This looks like a login verification, and he presumably wants to use the data from the row.

Comment: good point, in which case @GreyMurav answered it